# Migrate user from old AD to new AD

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, migration, user, content-migration, sid

I am finalising a migration and am currently trying to migrate my users from the old AD to the new one so that permissions and stuff fall in to place.

I'm using the command like so...

```
 stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin "i:0#.w|oldAD\username" -newlogin "i:0#.w|newAD\user.name"
```

Sharepoint shell is advising me **SID history can only be enforced in Windows authentication mode.**

It doesn't appear as an error as such, but I wasnt sure that the consequences of this are?

I understand I can use **–IgnoreSID** to surpress this and continue, but I do not know if that will mean further issues down the line.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following link with solutions to the potential problems that could arise. Let me know if you have anymore questions.

**[The SharePoint and SIDHistory problem](http://activedirectoryfaq.com/2014/09/domain-user-migration-sharepoint-and-sidhistory/)**

> Microsoft Sharepoint 2007, 2010 and 2013 do not support the access to
>   SharePoint content based on authorizations given by the SIDHistory. In
>   case user accounts are migrated into another Active Directory domain
>   and the SharePoint farm remains in the source domain for the time
>   being, the migrated user account cannot access SharePoint contents.
>
> The user can still access SharePoint manually with their account from
>   the source domain, but this can only serve as a workaround.

If you aren't changing the usernames, you could try the suggested PowerShell script.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$users = get-SPUser -web “https://webapplication/sites/sitecollection“
foreach ($oldUser in $users)
{
$oldUserSTR = $oldUser.userlogin
$newUser = $oldUserSTR.replace(“oldDomain“, “newDomain“)
move-SPUser -Identity $oldUser -NewAlias $newUser -IgnoreSID
}
```